# unmet dependencies padoka ppa

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

How can i solve this problem?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.85-0~x~padoka0) but 2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.85-0~x~padoka0) but 2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.85-0~x~padoka0) but 2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.85-0~x~padoka0) but 2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1 is to be installed
 mesa-vdpau-drivers : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.85-0~x~padoka0) but 2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

sudo apt-get install -f
Does not help

after run this comand

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcuda1-375 libdrm-common nvidia-opencl-icd-375
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
44 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/59,7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14,3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 271931 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85-0~x~padoka0_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1) ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.85-0~x~padoka0) over (2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85-0~x~padoka0_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.85~git20171023.e580be90-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85-0~x~padoka0_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1) ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.85-0~x~padoka0) over (2.4.84+git20171019.511c71c8-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85-0~x~padoka0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.85~git20171023.e580be90-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85-0~x~padoka0_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85-0~x~padoka0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85-0~x~padoka0_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85-0~x~padoka0_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem with upgrading libglvnd-core-dev from the Padoka PPA.